# Samba permissions being ignored

Tags: samba, permissions

I have defined the following share in smb.conf

```
[development_server]
    comment = Development directories
    path = /sites
    writeable = yes
    valid users = @dev
    guest ok = no
    directory mask = 0775
    create mask = 0775
```

The problem is that whenever I create a file within windows the permissions of that file are set as 764 instead of being set as 755. Directories however are set correctly with 775. I am confused. I tried setting the following:

```
[global]
    unix extensions = yes
```

But this did not help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the security mode settings within my configuration (or lack there of). The following smb.conf configuration is now working for me and all users within my security group "dev" now have 775 for all files they create within the share:

```
[development_server]
    comment = Development directories
    path = /sites
    writeable = yes
    valid users = @dev
    guest ok = no

    create mask = 0775
    force create mode = 0775
    security mask = 0775
    force security mode = 0775

    directory mask = 0775
    force directory mode = 0775
    directory security mask = 0775
    force directory security mode = 0775
```

I found this solution while digging through [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97669/i-cant-get-samba-to-set-proper-permissions-on-created-directories)

Comment: These configurations are deprecated "security mask, force security mode, directory security mask, force directory security mode"

Answer (score 2):

`create mask` can only be used to prevent a permission bit to be set, as the mask is bitwise `AND`ed with the bits the client tried to set. If the mask is set to 7, but the client tries something less, e.g. 6, the client "wins" as `0 AND 1` for the execute bit is `0`.

`force create mode` works the other way around, it will bitwise `OR` the mode to what the client tries to set, so if you set a `7` here, every bit will end up  with `x OR 1`, which is always `1`.

To force the value `0775` regardless of what the client tries to set, you have to combine the two:

```
create mask = 0770   (0000 would also work)
force create mode = 0775
```

See the [documentation](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#CREATEMASK).

Comment: after setting create mask = 0770 and force create mask = 0775 my permissions then become 760 on newly created files

Answer (score 2):

Check `obey PAM restrictions` parameter. If enabled Samba will create files with umask restriction for given user.

Answer (score 1):

A word of *warning* on testing this problem:

After suffering the same issue I discovered that, in my case at least, it was conditional;

- when I create a file in the samba share using context-menu new-file ('New Text File.txt') it **does not** set the group-write bit on that file (0750)
- when I create a new file using context-menu new-file and change its name before pressing enter it **does set the group-write bit** on that file! (0770)

My solution was the one @niziak warned about.
Do not use *obey PAM restrictions* (defaults to no).

Comment: I have double-checked this with Windows 10 as a client of a Samba-hosted AD domain (version 4.17.8 on Debian Bookworm), and no matter how this is done, the permissions are set to `drwxrwx---` for directories and `-rw-rw----` for regular files no matter how `create mask` or `directory mask` are set (in my case it's 0640 for the former and 0750 for the latter) and independent of `obey pam restrictions` (I've checked with both settings). The permission bits for world-access are correctly cleared, though.